# how to jQuery animate rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, animation, rotation

I have this jQuery plugin here:

```
$.fn.jqrotate = function(degrees, options)
{
    var options = $.extend({ 
                animate : false // not yet implemented
                }, options);

                return this.each(function()
                {
                    var $this = $(this);

                  var oObj = $this[0];
                  var deg2radians = Math.PI * 2 / 360;

                  var rad = degrees * deg2radians;
                  var costheta = Math.cos(rad);
                  var sintheta = Math.sin(rad);

                  a = parseFloat(costheta).toFixed(8);
                  b = parseFloat(-sintheta).toFixed(8);
                  c = parseFloat(sintheta).toFixed(8);
                  d = parseFloat(costheta).toFixed(8);

                  $this.css( {  '-ms-filter' : 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=' + a + ', M12=' + b + ', M21=' + c + ', M22=' + d + ',sizingMethod=\'auto expand\')',
                                'filter' : 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=' + a + ', M12=' + b + ', M21=' + c + ', M22=' + d + ',sizingMethod=\'auto expand\')',
                                '-moz-transform' :  "matrix(" + a + ", " + c + ", " + b + ", " + d + ", 0, 0)",
                                '-webkit-transform' :  "matrix(" + a + ", " + c + ", " + b + ", " + d + ", 0, 0)",
                                '-o-transform' :  "matrix(" + a + ", " + c + ", " + b + ", " + d + ", 0, 0)"
                  });


                });  
            };
```

That I use like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var degree = 0;
    $(".big-ball").click(function(){
        degree += 90;
        $(this).jqrotate(degree);
    });
});
```

That does the job for rotating it very nice, but I'd like to animate the rotation process, what can be done to make it happen with the given plugin? (fyi: changing `animate: false` to `true` doesn't enable it :) )

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried adding transition property to .big-ball? .big-ball { transition: all 1s; } for example; Any further modifications on its position/rotation/etc should be animated then

Comment: Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/CqAU2/